# getting from android to Google app engine

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Could someone please provide me with a link to a tutorial that shows and explains how to send data from an android emulator to a Google app engine. I have googled it myself but am not having any luck finding any good ones. I am a beginner so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: beginner in android or appengine or both or client/server? how beginner is your beginner-ness? If you are totally beginner, I would advice you to start with android stand alone first.

Answer (score 10):

The standard way would be to create a REST service on GAE and then call it from Android.

Server side: there are several REST libraries, my personal choice is [Resteasy](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.1.GA/userguide/html/index.html).

Android side: there are [numerous examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267928/android-rest-client-sample) how to consume REST services. You might also want to look at [Android client from Spring](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android).

For a complete example you might want to look at the [source of LeanEngine](http://www.lean-engine.com/).

Comment: Nice one! Just what I needed! Thx!