# Is Restlet on Android portable to Java SE/EE?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, restlet

I have used Jersey for creating rest-requests, but it won't work on android at the moment. So i am thinking about an alternative like Restlet.

As i understand that Restlet would need an editions to get it working on android, i am thinking about compatibility on other java-platforms, because i am creating a library which should be useable on every java-plattform.

If it isn't portable, alternative might be to create an more versions of my library like android-edition or java-se-edition, another possibility is to implement it on my own, forget about every library, which might hurt portability.

What would be you solution on a Java-Rest-Library which should work on every Java-Platform even on  Android?

Comment: seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267928/android-rest-client-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Restlet Framework has exactly this goal in mind, facilitating the portability of your client and server-side HTTP application on all Java related platforms. We do support a consistent Restlet API across Android, Java SE, Java EE, GAE, OSGi and GWT.

See Javadocs for each "edition" of Restlet here:

http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.1/