# User Authentication

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-security

I'm developing a small app, I have an asp.net web application with a WCF data service. On my app, the data service is exposed to Android, and I want to authenticate the users.

The user's credentials will be stored in a database.
Is it possible to use membership and role provider to authenticate the users?
If not, what is the best authentication method, so that I can give permissions to some operations and deny it for other operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option I've seen used often is to use HTTPS and pass through your user credentials on each call using a RESTful service. Obviously keep your security layer at the server side and return failure codes when the credentials aren't valid.

There are tonnes of examples on the web, including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267928/android-rest-client-sample) SO answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i' will check that method.