# Java - REST Client

Tags: java, android, rest, rest-client

I almost finished my RESTful API.
I created the API with PHP and using SLIM Framework.

And for the last step, I should consume the RESTful API that I've created before on Android application.

I've some question to ask.

1. Is it possible to use the RESTful API that I made with SLIM and PHP in Android Application ?
2. If the answer is 'YES', is there a framework or library can be used ?

Thanks before :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android REST client, Sample?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267928/android-rest-client-sample)

Comment: I don't get it. why would it matter for your android application in what language you built your REST service?

Comment: You might want to do a simple web search for 'Android rest client` and will find a nice [spring tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/) and at least one [good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8697827/510711)

Comment: flob : I just search for my answers, most of all question I read before didn't answer my question.. sorry.. but thanks :)

Comment: @popovits : haha I know, I just feel scared for the RESTful API that I created before can't be compatible with android app, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take one of:

- [Android Async HTTP](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http)
- [Spring](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/)
- [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/)
- [RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid)
- [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice)
- [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)
- [Httpzoid](https://github.com/kodart/Httpzoid) see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17636869/510711)

(Take a look at the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8697827/510711) where I took most of the list from)

Comment: sorry for duplicatin, but thanks before :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is possible. RESTful API is the same regardless of the language used. Just make sure that's work correctly using HTTP methods. Check this tutorial http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/

Answer (score 0):

I recomend use https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http
For me it's best android rest client library

Comment: ok I will surf to the site ! thanks before